NUCLEO stm32 board and gpios
Im looking for a microcontroller with a lot of gpio. I have looked into NUCLEO-H755ZI-Q. As I understand it shall provide me with 144 gpio but im not sure if I need some header for this to happen? I have read about ST Zio and morpho connectivity but not sure what exactly that means? How can I access all gpio? What exactly do I need or do NUCLEO-H755ZI-Q provide all these outputs out of the box?
Are there any microcontroller with even more gpio?

Both Infineon and NXP has ARM Cortex M controllers with over 200 IO pins. Don't know if you get eval boards like the STM Nucleo series for them, though. If not, you have to design your own board.

^^^ Agreed with this. Building your own board isn't as difficult as it sounds. Many suppliers have schematics for their demo boards so you can copy some of the basic designs like powering the chip but after that, you can customize the hardware to fit your needs for pure GPIO.

No the board will not give you 144 GPIO pins.
The MCU on the board has a total of 144 pins in the package.
There are much less IO pins available for GPIO, because the MCU has a lot of power supply, ground, and other IO pins reserved for onboard peripherals such as USB and Ethernet.
All IO pins you have available are in the pin headers, but some of them may still be unavailable for your use if they are reserved for onboard peripherals.
It looks like the Morpho headers don't come with a pin header so you need to solder in the pin headers or wires you want.
For further details see board documentation such as manual and schematics.

So I dont actually need to buy something else to use the availible gpio gpios. I can just solder a header on morpho and use the other header st zio header
